# Inserting data from SQLite database into QTableWidget

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt5

I want to load data from my SQLite database into QTableWidget. I tried to realize it via for loop but only row numbers appear on the widget. If I print out my data it appears on the terminal.

terminal result:
[image: terminal result]

Result:
[image: Result]

Database:
[image: Database]

```
class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        loadUi("adamant.ui",self)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(0, 250)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(1, 100)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(2, 350)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(3, 250)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(4, 200)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(5, 100)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(6, 150)        
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["ID","FirstN","LastN","Patr", "Order_num", "phone", "email"])

        self.loaddata()

   def loaddata(self):
       connection = sqlite3.connect('adamant.db')
       cur = connection.cursor()
       sqlstr = 'SELECT * FROM Customers'

       tablerow=0
       results = cur.execute(sqlstr)
       self.tableWidget.setRowCount(40)
       for row in results:
           self.tableWidget.setItem(tablerow, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(row[0]))
           self.tableWidget.setItem(tablerow, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(row[1]))
           self.tableWidget.setItem(tablerow, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(row[2]))
           self.tableWidget.setItem(tablerow, 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(row[3]))
           self.tableWidget.setItem(tablerow, 4, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(row[4]))
           self.tableWidget.setItem(tablerow, 5, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(row[5]))
           self.tableWidget.setItem(tablerow, 6, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(row[6]))


           tablerow+=1
     # main
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainwindow = MainWindow()
widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
widget.addWidget(mainwindow)
widget.setFixedHeight(850)
widget.setFixedWidth(1120)
widget.show()
try:
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
except:
    print("Exiting")
```

Comment: Have you created an emtpy QTableWidget in Designer (no rows, no columns)? If that's so, you must specify it, using [`setColumnCount()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#setColumnCount).

Comment: add `self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(7)`

Comment: Thank you very much, I have forgotten to add columns.